# R - dbWriteTable makes capital letters in column names

Tags: r, dbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a table (in Snowflake db) with exactly the same column names as I keep in the R data.frame object:

```
    'data.frame':   1 obs. of  26 variables:
     $ Ship_To                 : chr "0002061948"
     $ Del_Coll_Indicator      : chr "D"
     $ Currency                : chr "GBP"
     $ Total_Volume            : num 0
     $ Total_Quantity          : num 0
    ...
```

There is no problem with the table creation:

```
dbWriteTable(con = my_db$con, name = "test5", value = df)
```

but all column names in the database are converted to upper cases:

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  26 variables:
 $ SHIP_TO                 : chr "0002061948"
 $ DEL_COLL_INDICATOR      : chr "D"
 $ CURRENCY                : chr "GBP"
...
```

Is there any way to keep in the table original names from R's data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As covered by Snowflake's [SQL reference docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#label-identifier-casing), when identifiers (such as column names) are unquoted at creation, Snowflake *will upper case them*, and treat them as case-insensitive. Any **quoted identifiers** will be kept as-is and treated as a case-sensitive identifier.

Alter the data frame column names (`colnames(df)`) to use a quoted identifier format via the `dbQuoteIdentifier(my_db$con, each_column_name)` [DBI function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/SQL). This should help preserve the casing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!
Now it works like a charm. I had to use quotation characters for column names like this:

colnames(df) = paste0('\"',colnames(df), '\"')

... and now everything is fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for commenting back. Consider adding an answer or marking this one solved so others can find it easily: https://xkcd.com/979/ 